# What would happen if you went back to help your friend on the bridge?

Tags: undertale

When you're running across the bridge to Undyne battle in a pacifist run and your friend falls, what would happen if you go back?

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Arqade! Can you clarify your question to include the specific scenario that you're hoping to get more information on? What friends you're referring to, if it's a pacifist/neutral/genocide run, and any other info that can help give context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you help the monster kid, they will defend you from Undyne, giving you a chance to escape (though you still battle her later). This is reflected in the dialog but has no other effects.